# C# Combine two files to run via output file - File Binder

Tags: c#, arrays, file, byte

I'm trying to code a file binder.

I combined the array of bytes from the two files to be written into the output file.

It seems that I am merging the two files instead of binding them because I want to be able to run both files when I run the output file.

Is there a way I can combine the two arrays but split them during run time to be able to run both files?

or is there any other way I can code the file binder?

Code:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text != null & textBox2.Text !=null)
        {
            string filepath1 = this.textBox1.Text;
            byte[] Bytes1 = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath1);

            string filepath2 = this.textBox2.Text;
            byte[] Bytes2 = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath2);

            byte[] combinedbytes = new byte[Bytes1.Length + Bytes2.Length];

            Array.Copy(Bytes1, 0, combinedbytes, 0, Bytes1.Length);
            Array.Copy(Bytes2, 0, combinedbytes, Bytes1.Length, Bytes2.Length);

            File.WriteAllBytes(outfile, combinedbytes);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but not without intermediate file or intermediate structure.

1. You can store in separate file, length of both byte arrays.

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, new[] { Bytes1.Length, Bytes2.Length });

byte[] Bytes1 = new byte[File.ReadLines(path)[0]];
byte[] Bytes2 = new byte[File.ReadLines(path)[1]];
```

Then load those 2 files and perform Array.Copy from your merged file. To separate arrays

2. Use one text (can be binary) file and create structure so you will know length of arrays you merged and their content. JSON should work for you.

```
{
    Bytes1: //Your bytes here,
    Bytes2: //Your second bytes here
}
```